# Get next 5 lines after regexp is matched in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

How to get the next 5 lines after a certain pattern is matched in TCL
I've some 30lines of output and need only few lines in between...

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to split the output into a list of lines so you can use `lsearch`:

```
% set output [exec seq 10]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
% set lines [split $output \n]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
% set idx [lsearch -regexp $lines {4}]
3
% set wanted [lrange $lines $idx+1 $idx+5]
5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append something to your regular expression! Like this:

```
([^\n]*\n){5}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `[*\n]`? If you meant `[^\n]`, you do know that the `.` metacharacter is a shortcut for that, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. About your suggestion, not always. It often does match newlines, so I've gotten used to using a more specific metacharacter when it matters whether it matches them.

Comment: If you use `-line`, `.` won't match newlines, and you can use the expression `{4\n((?:.*\n){5})}` to capture five lines following a line containing the string `4`. It's not really a good idea, though. Besides, appending `([^\n]*\n){5}` to the regular expression only captures the fifth line.

Answer (score 0):

Glenn Jackman's solution is probably better, but the line processing command in `fileutil` can be preferable for some variations.

```
package require fileutil
```

Given a file that looks like this:

```
% cat file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Now, for each line in the file

```
set n 0
set re 4
set nlines 5
::fileutil::foreachLine line file.txt {
    if {$n > 0} {
        puts $line
        incr n -1
    }
    if {$n == 0 && [regexp $re $line]} {
        set n $nlines
    }
}
```

If the counter `n` is greater than 0, print the line and decrement. If `n` is equal to 0 and the regular expression matches the line, set `n` to `$nlines` (5).

```
# output:
5
6
7
8
9
```

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)